# mobile navbar not collapsing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the navbar to disappear when it reaches 768px and become a button on the right side. The button will open the navbar back, I have added code to make the navbar to disappear at 768px but it doesn't work. Not so sure what is wrong since the button shows 768px. But the navbar does not disappear at 768px.

```
html
   
<nav id="Nav" class="navbar nav">
      <div class="container flex">
        <img src="Week5saasappassets-210323-142515 (1)/Week-5-saas-app-assets/project_logo/logo.svg"  alt="Company logo" class="company-logo">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarDropdown"><span>&#9776;</span></button>
      <div class="nav-parent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Learn</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Price</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-green">Hire us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

```
css
navbar-toggler{
  position: absolute;
  right: var(--size-20);

  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.navbar-toggler span{
  color: var(--pureblack);
  font-size: var(--size-20);
}

[aria-controls="navbarDropdown"]{
  display: none;
}


.navbar .container{
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 500;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-brand{
  cursor: pointer;

}
.nav-parent{
  margin-left: auto;
}

.navbar-nav{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


.navbar-nav li{
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-link a{
  margin-right: 2.5rem;
}


responsive
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
[aria-controls="navbarDropdown"] {
  display: block;
 }

 [aria-expanded="false"] ~ ul{
   display: none;
 }

 [aria-expanded="true"] ~ ul{
   display: block;
 }
}
```

```
javascript
<script>
    const navButton = document.querySelector('button[aria-expanded]');
  
  function toggleNav({ target }){
    const expanded = target.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true' ||  false;
    navButton.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !expanded);
  }
  
  navButton.addEventListener('click', toggleNav);
  </script>
```

Comment: Your media query doesn't have anything that says to toggle display: none; on the nav-parent class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css to select the ul via the button,

```
[aria-expanded="false"] ~ ul{
   display: none;
 }

 [aria-expanded="true"] ~ ul{
   display: block;
 }
```

Won't work, here's why. The tilde (~) is a [sibling selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators). For this selector to work the way you specified, your ul would have to appear after the button, within the same container, like this:

```
<button ariaexpanded="true"></button>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-link">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
</ul>
```

So if your .nav-parent div isn't being used, you could try remove that and it will likely work.

This is my approach when doing mobile menus. Have your media query target a certain container which goes to 100% viewport width and height at your mobile breakpoint. It should also be offset vertically or horizontally out of the view of the user. Then you just need some JS to toggle a 'showing' class which positions the menu on the user's screen:
Your toggle nav function:

```
function toggleNav({ target }){
    const expanded = target.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true' ||  false;
    navButton.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !expanded);
    // Toggle nav 'showing' class
    if (nav.classList.contains('showing')) {
        nav.classList.remove('showing')
    } else {
        nav.classList.add('showing')
    }
  }

// Close menu button
closeNavButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.remove('showing')
})
```

CSS:

```
/* Don't show the 'close' button on desktop */
.nav-parent button {
  display: none;
}

/* Mobile breakpoint */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
[aria-controls="navbarDropdown"] {
  display: block;
 }

 [aria-expanded="false"] ~ ul{
   display: none;
 }
 
 /* Your menu now takes up 100% of screen, and is offset to the left */
 .nav-parent {
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   top: 0;
   left: -100vw;
   transition: all 0.25s ease;
   background: white;
 }
 /* When the showing class is added, it will position itself on the screen */
 .nav-parent.showing {
   opacity: 1;
   left: 0;
 }
}
```

HTML (add a close-menu button)

```
<div class="nav-parent">
        <button>
          Close
        </button>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          ...
</div>
```

[JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/seanb0/ufzvL0r7/5/)

There's lots of room for creativity.

Comment: thanks for your help! still a beginner at this